# Panel-Corrected Standard Error Estimation (pcse) model with unbalanced data

Tags: r, linear-regression, panel

I have an unbalanced panel of 108 countries over a period of 28 years, and I am trying to estimate a model with Panel-Corrected Standard Errors. But my attempts are failing because I get the following error message:
`Error in pcse(lm, groupN = data$id, groupT = data$time, pairwise = TRUE):   Length of groupN and groupT must equal nrows of using data.`

My dataset looks roughtly like this:

```
library(plm)
data(Grunfeld)
setDT(Grunfeld)[firm %in%c(1,4,7,9) & year>=1950,inv:=NA] # creating unbalanced data
head(Grunfeld,20)
# firm year   inv  value capital
# 1:    1 1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8
# 2:    1 1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6
# 3:    1 1937 410.6 5387.1   156.9
# 4:    1 1938 257.7 2792.2   209.2
# 5:    1 1939 330.8 4313.2   203.4
# ....
# 15:    1 1949 555.1 3700.2  1020.1
# 16:    1 1950    NA 3755.6  1099.0
# 17:    1 1951    NA 4833.0  1207.7
# 18:    1 1952    NA 4924.9  1430.5
# 19:    1 1953    NA 6241.7  1777.3
# 20:    1 1954    NA 5593.6  2226.3
```

Whereby, for some firms, I have missing values on my dependent variable (inv) for a few of the last years (1950-54).

To calculate my case I am first estimating the linear model. I am using lags for theoretical reasons.

```
lm<- lm(inv ~ lag(value,k=1)+ lag(capital, k = 1) + as.factor(year) + as.factor(firm), data = Grunfeld)
summary(lm)
```

And then I try to add my panel corrected standard errors, however when I run the command the error message appears.

```
lm.pcse <- pcse(lm, groupN=Grunfeld$firm, groupT=Grunfeld$year,
                 pairwise=TRUE)
#Error in pcse(lm, groupN = Grunfeld$firm, groupT = Grunfeld$year, #pairwise = TRUE) : 
#  Length of groupN and groupT must equal nrows of using data.
```

Does anyone knowe how I can go about this issue?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never been able to get this package to work outside of the included demo--but
I have solved this problem before (only to encounter a new one!).

Your error is likely caused by the fact that the "using data" does not include the observations omitted by `lm()` but your groupN and T vectors do (as they are extracted from the full datatable, with missing data and all).

What I've done in the past is run the model, extract the "using data" with `model.frame()` then use that new dataframe to run `lm()` and `pcse()`. Something like the following:

```
lm <- lm(inv ~ lag(value,k=1)+ lag(capital, k = 1) + as.factor(year) + as.factor(firm), data = Grunfeld)

dfPCSE <- model.frame(lm)

lm <- lm(inv ~ lag(value,k=1)+ lag(capital, k = 1) + as.factor(year) + as.factor(firm), data = dfPCSE)

lm.pcse <- pcse(lm, groupN=dfPCSE$firm, groupT=dfPCSE$year,
                 pairwise=TRUE)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for taking the time to contribute to this question. If you have a related question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question to help provide context.

Answer (score 0):

I once experienced this issue. Use na.omit to remove the missing values in your dataset.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).